# How do I reverse a css export in Adobe Fireworks?

Tags: css, adobe-fireworks, png

I have exported a fireworks `.fw.png` file to a `.png` and a `.css` file.  I have lost the `.fw.png` files and the `.css` file has 200+ objects.   Is there anyway to recreate the slices from the CSS code?

Comment: you can open it in a browser (image+CSS) then do a screen shot.

Comment: no, that isn't re-creating the fireworks .fw.png object

Comment: oh, you want to some how convert it back into the source FW PNG file. Yea, no way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks scott, i tend to agree.... ;-)

what i ended up doing was looking at the code that fireworks creates for a slice.  I then used the CSS and parsed it through a regular expression to extract the coordinates and slice name.  Then i pasted these into excel, translated the numbers to the required format and used the  concatenate function to generate a fireworks call.  i saved these as a stored fireworks macro.

this got the slices done, but i couldn't work out how to do the layers quickly, so that was a manual process.

Comment: That's an impressive solution! I would have probably just re-imported each of the individual PNGs back into one FW PNG file, assemble them back together, then just draw new slices snapping to the boundaries of the individual PNGs.

Comment: "stored fireworks macro" = javascript, vbscript, applescript, magic...?

Comment: Note that posting the source code for the macro (or at least the crucial bit) would be of interest to me and to posterity.

Comment: sorry, but it is long gone, i hope to never need it again, and it is the last time i trust our IT dept. to restore a backup....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

You will have to manually reconstruct things using the CSS as a guide but there's no way to transfer CSS to objects in Fireworks. Also be aware the ability Fireworks has to save a layered PNG file is proprietary to Fireworks. Standard PNG files don't contain layers and construction elements.